# I want to hide the calender by clicking anywhere on screen..toogleCalendar is the calendar icon

Tags: reactjs

i want to close my calendar if i click anywhere on the screen...toogleCalendar is the calendar icon..which controls calender action..I want to close calendar when if user clicks anywhere on screen..

```
     let comp = modal ?
            <div className={styles.calendarInput}>
                <span onClick={toogleCalendar}>{value ? Dates.format(date, Dates.formats.americanMediumDate) : null}</span>
                <div className={visible ? '_common_form__show' : '_common_form__hidden'}>
                    {calendar}
                </div>
            </div>:
            calendar;
        return (
            <div>
                <label><Label config={{label, helpText}} /></label>
                {comp}
            </div>
        );
    };

    const CalendarExtended = compose(
        withState('visible', 'setVisible', false),
        withHandlers({
            toogleCalendar: ({setVisible, visible}) => () => {
                setVisible(!visible);
            }
        })
    )(Calendar);.
```

calender should close on click anywhere on screen

Answer (score 0):

1) Using reference(ref), we can get the class based on the click event outside the div.
2)By default, the state of the calendar class will be true and on clicking outside, I'm setting the value to false.Hope this helps.

```html
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isOpen: true
    };
  } 
 
handleClick = (e) => {
    if (this.toogleCalendarClass &&
      !this.toogleCalendarClass.contains(e.target)) {
      this.setState({ isOpen: false});
    }
  }


componentWillMount = () => {
    document.addEventListener('click', this.handleClick);
  }

  componentWillUnmount = () => {
    document.removeEventListener('click', this.handleClick);
  }


this.toogleCalendarClass = null;
let comp = modal ?
            <div className={styles.calendarInput}>
                <span onClick={toogleCalendar}  ref={(input) => {
          this.toogleCalendarClass = input;
        }
        }>{value ? Dates.format(date, Dates.formats.americanMediumDate) : null}</span>
        
                <div className={`visible ${this.state.isOpen ? '_common_form__show' : '_common_form__hidden'}`}>
                    {calendar}
                </div>
            </div>:
            calendar;
        return (
            <div>
                <label><Label config={{label, helpText}} /></label>
                {comp}
            </div>
        );
    };

    const CalendarExtended = compose(
        withState('visible', 'setVisible', false),
        withHandlers({
            toogleCalendar: ({setVisible, visible}) => () => {
                setVisible(!visible);
            }
        })
    )(Calendar);
```

Comment: code works fine after adding a little snippet.. coz i already defined my constructor in another file.. anyways thankss for a big help..